# Is it possible to get a recyclerview/listview to navigate to different screens?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I've seen many Kotlin recyclerview tutorials however they all seem to be based on item reviews/contacts lists which all bring you to the same screen when selected, albeit with the different viewholder content. I was wondering if it's possible to use a standalone recyclerview/listview for navigation instead of a navigation drawer which doesn't seem suitable for extensive directories. And if so are there any tutorials for this out there?

Essentially something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC6fU.png):

Comment: What do you mean by `bring you to the same screen when selected`? i think you could create your own ArrayAdapter and handle the OnClickListener.

Comment: Whatever class you use for the items in the list can include a function reference (or override an abstract function) for what to do or where to go when it is clicked. Then your Adapter can invoke that function for the item when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, you can set a tag on each view in your RecyclerView in onBindViewHolder, and in the click listener, you can get the tag and act according to which tag it is.

You can make your RecyclerView adapter extend `View.onClickListener`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OpportunityViewHolder, position: Int) {
  // Differentiate between items by having a base class that you implement for your different items
  val item = getItem(position)
  item.tag = when(item) {
    is ThisThing -> "thisThing"
    is ThatThing -> "thatThing"
    is AnotherThing -> "anotherThing"
  }
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {
  when(v.tag) {
    "thisThing" -> // do something
    "thatThing" -> // something else... 
}
```

Of course, you would probably want to use an enum for the tag possibilities, or constant values, or even use the class names

```
enum class Tag {
  THIS_THING, THAT_THING...
}

companion object {
  private const val THIS_THING = "THIS_THING"
  ...
}

// Inside classes
companion object {
  val name = ThisThing::class.simpleName
  ...
}
```